# The Gauss-Bonnet theorem for Sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, euler-characteristics

## Euler Characteristic of Sheaves and the Generalized Gauss-Bonnet Theorem

Consider a sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ over a site $\mathscr{(C,J)}$, where $\mathscr{C}$ is a small category with a coverage $\mathscr{J}$. The Euler characteristic is defined as $\chi(\mathscr{F})=\sum_{i\in\mathbf{Z}_0^+}(-1)^i\dim_\mathbb F(H^i(\mathscr{C},\mathscr{F}))$.

The Euler characteristic satisfies, on a compact orientable $2n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold without boundary, the generalized Gauss-Bonnet theorem:
$$\int_M \mathrm{Pf}(\Omega)=(2\pi)^n\chi(M), \, $$
Here $\Omega$ is the curvature form of the Levi-Civita connection and the Pfaffian of $\Omega$ is $\mathrm{Pf}(\Omega)$.

## The Question

> Is there an analog of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem in algebraic geometry? Specifically, is it possible to define the "curvature form $\mathscr{O}$ of a (Levi-Civita) connection on the quasi-coherent sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ over the site $\mathscr{(C,J)}$ ([this book, perhaps?](http://books.google.com/books?id=W3QuH7yGB0cC&pg=PA297&lpg=PA297&dq=curvature+of+sheaf&source=bl&ots=7UwYSPyYAA&sig=q5DMa7xygU4rH680k4ccWEMprIc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ndmHU8-nBo6ZyASR-4DQDQ&ved=0CF8Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=curvature%20of%20sheaf&f=false))" and the "sheaf Pfaffian $\mathscr{Pf}$" to obtain something like the Gauss-Bonnet, e.g. $\int_\mathscr{F} \mathscr{Pf}(\mathscr{O})=(2\pi)^{\dim\mathscr{F}}\dim_\mathbb FH^0(\mathscr{C},\mathscr{F})$, with $\dim\mathscr{F}$ the [(pure)](http://books.google.com/books?id=J5P5YzTfCXEC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=dimension+of+a+sheaf&source=bl&ots=vXViaC2H62&sig=7FO2DE0i2BQydAJ9HfmOV6Oihw0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HteHU-u8BZezyASQjoKYDQ&ved=0CJgBEOgBMA8#v=onepage&q=dimension%20of%20a%20sheaf&f=false) [dimension](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88182/what-is-the-dimension-of-a-sheaf) of $\mathscr{F}$? (What is the "integral" supposed to be?)

## Thoughts

**Note 1:** As for what the integration might be, [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167577/expressing-the-lebesgue-integral-using-categories-the-difficulty-of-describing/167680#167680), which links to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.3188v1.pdf) (I believe Theorem 3.2 of that paper) provides a possible answer. However, I'm not sure if that's the "integration" wanted in the conjectured Gauss-Bonnet for sheaves.

**Note 2:** For constructible sheaves on reductive groups, I found the following paper by [V. Kiritchenko](http://www.mccme.ru/%7Evalya/gauss.pdf). I am interested in a generalization of this to sheaves over sites.

Comment: Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch is a reasonably close analogue, I guess. See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19308/is-there-an-analogue-of-curvature-in-algebraic-geometry .

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks. I did think at first that it might be the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch. Does any other theorem come closer than that? Thanks for the linked MO post. I'll go over the answers there!

Comment: It is important to make a distinction between the categories of sheaves that 'are' spaces (e.g. Sh(X) for X a manifold or scheme) and categories of sheaves that are 'categories of spaces' (e.g. Sh(S) for S=Cart (cartesian spaces and smooth maps) or S=Aff (affine schemes)). I would expect only the former to have a good notion of Gauss-Bonnet.

Comment: @DavidRoberts In other words, roughly speaking, we'd require $\mathscr{(C,J)}$ to be a sheaf of sets on some site $\mathrm{Loc}$ of local models with a Grothendieck topology on it ([nlab, generalized scheme](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+scheme)) for there to be a good notion of Gauss-Bonnet for sheaves. BTW, has the Gauss-Bonnet for sheaves been studied before?

Comment: No, I meant the other way around. The sheaves that would pop up should be sheaves on a space, not generalised spaces themselves.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Ah, yes! I see what you were saying now! Thanks for the clarification,

Comment: You could try something like ${d^{\nabla}}^2 = R$ for a Grothendieck connection, I don't know how to do this, though.

Comment: @user40276 I'll try that, but I do not know how to define a Pfaffian, or even a volume form on a sheaf. I don't even know if it's been done before. Has it?

Comment: Sorry, I've never seen this before, but there are sympletic forms in schemes, so you could try something analogous to manifolds.

Comment: @user40276 Maybe. I'll try to begin my construction as http://www.mccme.ru/~valya/gauss.pdf does. Might that work?

Comment: Well, if you want a very general Gauss-Bonnet (for instance in a topos), you should search something in synthetic differential geometry. I've friend that have worked on the field, so I will ask him.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14814/discussion-between-sanath-devalapurkar-and-user40276).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an answer in the case of constructible sheaves. The whole story can be found in Kashiwara and Shapira's book "Sheaves on Manifolds" Chapters VIII and IX.

I will try to summarize this rather  long story.     First, a prototype for a constructible sheaf is a locally constant sheaf supported on a *reasonable set*, e.g., semialgebraic, or subanalytic subset of some  Euclidean space  $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $\bR^n$.  For example the  constant sheaf with stalk $\bR$ defined on a compact  reasonable set is constructible. The Euler characteristic  of the cohomology of this sheaf is the Euler characteristic of that set.

In general, a constructible sheaf is really a complex of sheaves  whose  associated   cohomology sheaves are locally constant.

We  can form a $K$-theoretic group $K(\bR^n)$out of these   constructible sheaves   very much the way Grothendieck for coherent sheaves on algebraic manifolds. If $A, B,C$ are  constructible complexes of sheaves, then we have a $K$-theoretic equality  $B=A+C$  if   there exists a short exact  sequence  of complexes $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$  (It is a bit more complicated than this but I want to avoid talking about triangulated categories.) The Euler characteristic of the (hyper)cohomology of a complex $A$ induces  a group morphism

$$\chi: K(\bR^n)\to \mathbb{Z}.$$

Kashiwara and Schapira have shown that the Abelian group  $K(\bR^n)$  is isomorphic to two groups that have simpler descriptions.

The first group is the group $\newcommand{\eC}{\mathscr{C}}$ $\eC(\bR^n)$ of constructible  functions. These  are functions $f:\bR^n\to \mathbb{Z}$ with *finite* range such that, for any $t\in\bR$ $f^{-1}(t)$ is a subanalytic set.    We obtain  an Euler characteristic morphism

$$\chi:\eC(\bR^n)\to\mathbb{Z}, $$

defined by

$$\chi (f) =\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} n \chi\bigl(\;f^{-1}(n)\;\bigr). $$

The  second group is the group $\newcommand{\eL}{\mathscr{L}}$ $\eL(\bR^n)$ of  conical lagrangian cycles in $T^*\bR^n$.  These are cycles supported by   lagrangian  varieties in $T^*\bR^n$ which  are invariant under  the rescaling along the fibers of the cotangent bundle.

Joseph  Fu  has      given a very nice  geometric description of an isomorphism   $\eC(\bR^n)\to \eL(\bR^n)$. This isomorphism associates  to each constructible $f$ function a lagrangian cycle called the conormal cycle $C^f$  of   the constructible function $f$. For example, if  $f$ is the indicator function  of a compact, subanalytic submanifold $S\subset \bR^n$, then $C^f$  is the Lagrangian cycle  defined by the conormal bundle of $S$ which is a subbundle of $T^*\bR^n|_S$.

The *normal cycle* $N^f$ of a constructible  function $f$ is obtained by intersecting the conormal cycle $C^f$ with the unit sphere bundle of $T^*\bR^n$. Thus,  if  $f$ is the indicator function  of a compact, subanalytic submanifold $S\subset \bR^n$, then the normal cycle $N^f=N^S$ can be identified with the unit normal sphere bundle of the submanifold $S$. If $f$ is the characteristic function of a  compact domain $D$ with smooth boundary $\newcommand{\pa}{\partial}$ $\pa D$ then  the normal cycle is the graph of the  Gauss map

$$ n:\pa D \to S^{n-1}\subset \bR^n,\;\;p\mapsto n(p), $$

where $n(p)$ denotes the outer unit normal vector to $\pa D$ at $p$.$\newcommand{\bZ}{\mathbb{Z}}$

The Euler characteristic morphism $\chi: \eL(\bR^n)\to\bZ$  was given an explicit description by Fu.  More precisely there exists a universal form of degree $n-1$, $\omega\in \Omega^{n-1}(S^{n-1}\times \bR^n)$ such that, for any constructible function $f$, its Euler characteristic $\chi(f)$ is equal to the integral  of $\omega$ over  the normal cycle  $N^f$ which is naturally a   cycle in $S^{n-1}\times \bR^n$.  When $f$  is the indicator function of a submanifold, the above result is   none other that the usual Gauss-Bonnet.  When  $f$ is the indicator function of a compact  affine simplicial complex in $\bR^n$,  Fu's result   leads to the computation of the Euler characteristic of the complex   as an integral of a so called *curvature measure*.   You can learn more about  this at [Fu's homepage.](http://www.math.uga.edu/~fu/research/research.html)